# How to setup Raspberry Pi in headless mode for VNC?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

How do I setup a Raspberry Pi 3 running on Raspbian in headless mode for remote control via VNC with a laptop running Windows? I don't have an HDMI monitor around for initial setup. I only have an Ethernet cable, a WiFi network and keyboard and mouse to set it up. Can anyone give me specific directions on how to configure it in totally headless mode and /or a link for the same?

Answer (score 1):

To setup VNC you would need access to a Raspberry Pi console (terminal session) after the initial boot up.  Normally this is done through SSH.  However Raspbian, by default for security reasons, does not allow the SSH client to run.  To get around this, place an empty file called "ssh" with no extensions into the boot partition of the SDCard.  This should start the SSH client after boot up allowing you to login to the Raspberry Pi.

Now you can, [follow these instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md), set up a Virtual Network Console (VNC) server on the Raspberry Pi and a VNC client on your Windows box.